# Change color of an element in JavaScript with mouseover event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the color of an element `<div class="box"></div>` when the mouse passes over it but there has to be some kind of error on my code and I can't find the problem:

```js
let html = "";
for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
    html += `<div class="box"></div>`
}
document.querySelector(".grid").innerHTML += html;


/*CHANGE COLOR WHEN MOUSE GO OVER*/

let newColor = document.querySelector(".box")
newColor.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor)

function changeColor(){
    document.querySelector(".box").style.color = "green"
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Why JavaScript? `div.box:hover { color: green }`

Comment: _"there has to be some kind of error on my code"_ - Why do you think so? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `.querySelector()` only returns the _first_ element that matches the selector

Comment: Also your div elements contain no text. `color` sets **text** color. Did you mean `background-color`?

Comment: Andreas: I need to do it in JavaScript, with querySelectorAll still doesnt work. Conexo: sorry, backgroundcolor

Comment: @Andreas There is a big difference between OP's code and `div.box:hover { color: green }`. In OP's code the color won't change back. It's a one-way-toggle.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an array. How do you handle the array? The posted code works for the first element. Using `querySelectorAll` you have to add an event listener to each array element (e.g. in a loop or with `Array.prototype.forEach`).

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, but from the description _"when the mouse pass over it"_ I assumed that `:hover` would do the job. Yet it is only a comment because I'm not 100% sure ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you javascript to this:

```
let newColor = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
          for (const color of newColor) {
            color.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
              color.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            });
          }
```

edit (explanation)

`querySelect` will only select first element (First '.box').

Changing it to `querySelectAll` you targer all of them in a array like object. You then use for loop to attach `addEventListener` to each element.